# Why is NHoldFirst not propagated to symbolic derivatives?

Tags: numerics, symbolic, expression-manipulation, hold, attributes

I encountered a nasty problem that `N` cannot evaluate expressions containing a symbolic `Derivative` of a multi-parameter function expecting an exact integer as its first argument.

```
Attributes[StieltjesGamma]
(* 
  {Listable, NHoldFirst, Protected, ReadProtected}
 *)

d = Derivative[0, 1][StieltjesGamma][1, 1]
(* 
  Derivative[0, 1][StieltjesGamma][1, 1]
*)

N[d, 10]
(* 
  StieltjesGamma::intnm: Non-negative machine-sized integer expected at position 1 
  in StieltjesGamma[1.000000000,1.000000000]. >>
  Derivative[0, 1][StieltjesGamma][1.000000000, 1.000000000]
*)
```

The first argument of `StieltjesGamma` only makes sense when it is an integer, and `NHoldFirst` is supposed to take care of this when approximate numeric calculations are performed. But in this case it goes unnoticed by `N` that results in a meaningless expression and an error message.

This also blocks some symbolic simplifications that internally rely on arbitrary-precision numeric calculations:

```
FullSimplify[d > 0]
(* 
  Derivative[0, 1][StieltjesGamma][1, 1] > 0
*)

FullSimplify[Floor[d]]
(* 
  Floor[Derivative[0, 1][StieltjesGamma][1, 1]]
*)
```

There is a workaround: apply `N` directly to the second argument:

```
MapAt[N[#, 10] &, d, 2]
(* 
  0.70738627
*)
```

but, of course, it becomes cumbersome when a derivative occurs deeply nested in a more complex expression.

I understand that `NHoldFirst` is formally attached to the symbol `StieltjesGamma` itself, not to a [non-symbol head](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ExpressionsWithHeadsThatAreNotSymbols.html) `Derivative[0, 1][StieltjesGamma]`. But the behavior resulting from this seems wrong. Should it be considered as a bug that needs to be reported to *Mathematica* Tech Support, or there is a valid reason why `NHoldFirst` should not be propagated to derivatives? Do you know any simpler workarounds for this problem?

Comment: Very good question. Arguably you've found a corner case that's not properly handled (i.e., a bug).

Comment: This works: `N[Derivative[0, 1][StieltjesGamma][0, 1], 50]`, that is if the first argument is zero, but not apparently for positive integer arguments.  Odd.

Comment: @MichaelE2 That is probably because `N[0, 50]` evaluates to the exact integer `0`.

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov  Yes, that would explain it.  Interesting that `0` is treated as exact and `1` is not.

Answer (score 5):

This is only a hack, but maybe it just gives you short way out of this. Lately, we had a similar discussion in chat about `NValues` where the problem was related. It this cases Rojo wanted to use `NValues` to prevent some of the arguments to stay untouched by `N`. There too, the problem was when `N` was called from very outside and dived into the subexpressions where you are unable to detect it. Maybe you want to read [the chat-log of this conversation](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9781502#9781502).

A simple way to achieve a *back-conversion* of a real valued first argument to `StieltjesGamma` define an additional rule for this function and inject some code:

```
Unprotect[StieltjesGamma];

StieltjesGamma[a_Real, b_] := Block[{$HaveSeenThisDefinition = True},
  StieltjesGamma[Round[a], b]
] /; Not[TrueQ[$HaveSeenThisDefinition]];

Protect[StieltjesGamma];
```

When you now execute your examples (although you are still getting the warning messages) your result is computed correctly:

```
d = Derivative[0, 1][StieltjesGamma][1, 1];
N[d, 10]
(* 0.7073857926 *)
```

Side note, if you are not aware of the trick I used to inject code into a built-in function, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5149656/1078614) for more details. Especially, the comment of Leonid explains quite clearly how it works.